# Refresh page without save previous event

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a Session and a ViewState `(C# Event of a .aspx page)` to control PostBack to lock a confim button.

```
//bool control.
private Boolean isPageRefresh;

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["postids"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["postid"] = ViewState["postids"].ToString();
}
else
{
    if (ViewState["postids"].ToString() != Session["postid"].ToString())
    isPageRefresh = true;

    Session["postid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ViewState["postids"] = Session["postid"].ToString();
}
```

When I call the Event `(in method c#)` its works perfectly. But when I click in refresh page, the event happens again.

How do I to don't happens again every refresh page?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

When I call my page (in this case `RadWindowManager`) I can alter the Behaviors properties, only sending the icons that I need.

```
var window = new RadWindow
{
    NavigateUrl = "~/../..",
    VisibleOnPageLoad = true,
    Width = 920,
    Height = 600
};

var windowManager = new RadWindowManager();

windowManager.Behaviors = WindowBehaviors.Close | WindowBehaviors.Move | WindowBehaviors.Resize | WindowBehaviors.Maximize | WindowBehaviors.Minimize | WindowBehaviors.Pin;
windowManager.Windows.Add(window);
Form.Controls.Add(window);
```

If I have the controls postaback page as I talk above, this code work. Even if I clicked in "F5" de "father page" inhibits refresh.